# Explain the difference between “sollen” and “müssen” to a native Belarusian

Tags: difference, modal-verb, rule-of-thumb

I have a friend from Belarus with whom I speak German.
However, she always mixes up *sollen* and *müssen* and says things like

> Ich soll das prüfen.

instead of

> Ich muss das prüfen.

Is there a solid rule, which governs the use of *sollen* and *müssen?*

Comment: Not sure if I understand what you're asking. Müssen is much stronger than sollen. What kind of rule are you looking for, if the context doesn't tell you which to choose?

Comment: I think you might refer to the much more common confusion between "sollen", "willen" und "werden". Ist this right? Neither of you two have German as a native language, right? Your friend surely wanted to say "Ich will es prüfen" or maybe "Ich werde..."

Comment: Iam native German. But I hit a border here. "soll", "sollte" and "muss" are hard to explain

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ich beantworte die Frage auf Deutsch, weil ich mich in meiner Muttersprache besser ausdrücken kann.

Als Faustregel kann man den Unterschied daran festmachen, ob eine Strafe droht.

### müssen

Wenn jemand etwas tun *muss*, dann wird gefordert, dass die Sache auf jeden Fall getan wird. Die Nichtbefolgung kann bestraft werden. Ein Beispiel:

> Karl-Heinz muss seine Einkünfte versteuern.

Karl-Heinz ist gezwungen, seine Einkünfte zu versteuern. Ein Gesetz verlangt das von ihm. Natürlich kann Karl-Heinz die Entscheidung treffen, das trotz gesetzlicher Pflicht nicht zu tun, aber dann droht ihm eine Strafe.

> Nadine muss ihre Puppen in die Kiste räumen.

Hier kommt der Zwang nicht von von einem Gesetz, sondern von den Eltern. Auch hier hat Nadine die Möglichkeit dem Zwang nicht zu folgen, aber auch in diesem Fall hat das möglicherweise eine Strafe zur Folge.

### sollen

Wenn jemand etwas tun *soll*, dann ist diese Person aufgefordert die Sache zu erledigen, aber wenn sie es nicht tut, droht ihr von der Instanz, von der die Aufforderung kommt, keine Vergeltung. Wenn die Sache nicht erledigt wird, kann das zwar für irgend jemand von Nachteil sein, aber die Person, die aufgefordert wurde, hat keine unmittelbare Sanktion zu befürchten.

> Erika soll mehr Gemüse essen.

Erika erkennt (möglicherweise durch einen Hinweis von einem Arzt), dass es für sie vorteilhaft wäre, mehr Gemüse zu essen. Wenn sie das nicht tut, verbessert sich ihr Gesundheitszustand nicht. Aber wenn sie weiterhin so wenig Gemüse isst wie jetzt, wird sie von niemandem bestraft.

> Martin soll am Sonntag seine Schwiegermutter besuchen.

Martins Frau, deren Mutter, oder irgendwelche anderen Personen erwarten, dass Martin endlich mal seine Schwiegermutter besucht. Wenn Martin das nicht tut, werden einige Personen traurig sein, aber Martin wird nicht bestraft.

---

Die Strafandrohung kann zwar als Faustregel genommen werden, trifft die Sache aber trotzdem nicht exakt auf den Punkt.

Ein Beispiel:

> Arzt zur Patientin: »Sie müssen mehr Wasser trinken!«

Das ist eine eindringliche Aufforderung des Arztes an die Patienten. Wenn die Patientin aber weiterhin sowenig trinkt, wird sie weder vom Arzt nich von einem Gericht zur Zahlung einer Strafe verurteilt. Negative Auswirkungen wird die Frau zwar verspüren, aber das sind keine Sanktionen.

> Herr Mayer zu seinem Nachbarn, dem Herrn Müller: »Sie müssen die Birke aus ihrem Garten entfernen, ich bin allergisch gegen Birkenpollen!«

Der Herr Müller muss in Wirklichkeit gar nichts. Wenn er die Birke stehen lässt, hat er keine Strafe zu befürchten. Für Herrn Mayer wäre es aber sehr wichtig, wenn Herr Müller die Birke entfernen würde, daher greift er zu härteren Formulierung.

---

### »Du sollst nicht ...«

Gesetze, die von Ländern oder Staaten erlassen werden, sind immer so formuliert, dass klar ist, dass man etwas tun **muss**. Das Wort »sollen« wird man in Gesetzen nur selten finden.

Nun sind aber die zehn Geboten der Christen anders formuliert. Das steht z.B.:

> Du *sollst* nicht töten.

Das Problem hier ist, dass fast alle Gebote eine Verneinung enthalten. Die Variante

> Du *musst* nicht töten.

Bedeutet nämlich nicht, dass man aufgefordert wird, der Tätigkeit des Nichttötens nachzugehen, sondern sie bedeutet, dass kein Zwang vorliegt jemanden zu töten. Der Satz bedeutet also:

> Es ist dir erlaubt zu töten, aber niemand zwingt dich dazu.

Die korrekte Variante wäre eigentlich:

> Du *darfst* nicht töten.

Denn das heißt:

> Es ist dir nicht erlaubt zu töten.

Nun klingt aber in »darfst« irgendwie die Möglichkeit mit, sich frei entscheiden zu können. Daher hat Luther, als er diese Gebote übersetzt hat, das Wort »sollen« gewählt. Ich vermute auch, dass zu Luthers Zeiten die Bedeutung von »sollen« sich noch viel mehr mit »müssen« überlagert hat, als das heute nich der Fall ist.

(Anmerkung: Im hebräischen Originaltext kommt weder *sollen* noch *müssen* vor. Da lautet die entsprechende Stelle »לא תרצח׃«. Das erste Wort »לא« ist eine Verneinung, und kann als »nicht« oder »kein« übersetzt werden. Das zweite Wort »תרצח« bedeutet als Substantiv »Mord« und als Verb »morden« oder »ermorden«. Dieses Gebot lautet also eigentlich: »kein Mord« oder »nicht morden«.)

Comment: Wie immer eine sehr ausführliche Antwort von Dir. Aber: Der Teil mit der Strafe gefällt mir nicht so - Menschem *müssen* atmen, essen sterben - vollkommen ohne Strafandrohung, wenn sie's lassen...

Comment: Sehr gute Antwort. Vielen Dank! Mir fehlt noch eine Erklärung zu Sachen wie: "Ich muss jetzt ins Bett". Hier spricht die Person ja eher von einem selbst auferlegten Zwang (vgl "ich sollte jetzt lieber ins Bett gehen").

Comment: Und wenn Herr Müller die Birke nicht entfernt, klagt Herr Mayer eben. ;)

Answer (score 2):

> Ich muss gar nix, außer sterben. (Alles andre soll ich)

Is a standing idiom in my region and expresses the difference pretty well and from an maybe a bit extreme viewpoint (of maybe an extremely disobeying character). *müssen* is the inevitable that you very probably cannot evade doing. *sollen*, on the contrary always refers to something you have been asked for or ordered to by some "higher authority" and **maybe** can, or even plan to evade.

Comment: What a nice reductio ad absurdum.